# Post JSON data to elastic search using curl command

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to post Json file to elastic search and facing below errors

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost/test-index/doc -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json
```

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [test-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [test-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"},"status":400}
```

test.json content

```
{
  "name":"John Smith",
   "age":"38"

}
```

am I missing anything

Comment: Can you try this command instead? `curl -XPOST http://localhost/test-index/_doc -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json`

Answer (score 0):

To post Json data to elasticsearch using curl command, you can try out this command:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test-index/_doc -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json
```

[image]

The command with which, you are trying to post Json file, works fine with Postman.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error returned is

> "reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [test-index] as the final
>   mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"}]

it mean that your index already have a type _doc and you try to create a new type doc. As version ~7.?? of elastic support only one type you can't create your data.

You need to add "_" before doc in your request.

http://localhost/test-index/doc <-- not correct

http://localhost/test-index/_doc <-- correct